# PHP Restler Server 500 Error

Tags: php, restler

I've installed restler using composer.  I've set up a virtual host for it.  I'm able to go to my `localhost` in my browser and it shows some informational pages but as soon as I try one of the APIs I get a server `500 error`.

My PHP logs say:

```
Function    main
Error Type  E_ERROR
Source File /public/examples/_001_helloworld/index.php : 18
Error String    Class 'Luracast\Restler\Restler' not found
```

I'm using the example code straight out of the project. It looks like it has the require_once `'../../../vendor/restler.php'` and it seems to still have 500 errors.

I'm using PHP 5.4.16 on a Mac.

**Update**

Here are all of my logs:

```
[05-Sep-2013 17:05:09 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  include(/Users/ChrisLondon/composer/autoload_classmap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/ChrisLondon/personal/SuperfyMe/vendor/Luracast/Restler/AutoLoader.php on line 432
[05-Sep-2013 17:05:09 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/Users/ChrisLondon/composer/autoload_classmap.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library:/usr/local/zend/share/pear:/opt/local/lib/php') in /Users/ChrisLondon/personal/SuperfyMe/vendor/Luracast/Restler/AutoLoader.php on line 432
[05-Sep-2013 17:05:09 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  include(/Users/ChrisLondon/composer/autoload_namespaces.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/ChrisLondon/personal/SuperfyMe/vendor/Luracast/Restler/AutoLoader.php on line 432
[05-Sep-2013 17:05:09 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/Users/ChrisLondon/composer/autoload_namespaces.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library:/usr/local/zend/share/pear:/opt/local/lib/php') in /Users/ChrisLondon/personal/SuperfyMe/vendor/Luracast/Restler/AutoLoader.php on line 432
[05-Sep-2013 17:05:09 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in /Users/ChrisLondon/personal/SuperfyMe/vendor/Luracast/Restler/AutoLoader.php on line 154
[05-Sep-2013 17:05:09 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array in /Users/ChrisLondon/personal/SuperfyMe/vendor/Luracast/Restler/AutoLoader.php on line 155
[05-Sep-2013 17:05:09 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in /Users/ChrisLondon/personal/SuperfyMe/vendor/Luracast/Restler/AutoLoader.php on line 155
[05-Sep-2013 17:05:09 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array in /Users/ChrisLondon/personal/SuperfyMe/vendor/Luracast/Restler/AutoLoader.php on line 166
[05-Sep-2013 17:05:09 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /Users/ChrisLondon/personal/SuperfyMe/vendor/Luracast/Restler/AutoLoader.php on line 166
[05-Sep-2013 17:05:09 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  natsort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /Users/ChrisLondon/personal/SuperfyMe/vendor/Luracast/Restler/AutoLoader.php on line 167
[05-Sep-2013 17:05:09 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /Users/ChrisLondon/personal/SuperfyMe/vendor/Luracast/Restler/AutoLoader.php on line 170
[05-Sep-2013 17:05:09 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /Users/ChrisLondon/personal/SuperfyMe/vendor/Luracast/Restler/AutoLoader.php on line 170
[05-Sep-2013 17:05:09 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Luracast\Restler\Restler' not found in /Users/ChrisLondon/personal/SuperfyMe/public/examples/_001_helloworld/index.php on line 19
```

It seems like it's trying to find the autoload class here: `/Users/ChrisLondon/composer/autoload_classmap.php` but the file is actually here: `/Users/ChrisLondon/personal/SuperfyMe/vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my issue.

It turns out because I have a folder named `composer/` that happens to be two folders up from where the Restler app sits it ruins the Restler autoloader.  To solve the issue one needs to do one of the following:

1) Don't have any folder named `composer/` two folders up from where the Restler app resides

2) Modify the Restler autoloader to skip the folder (at the time of this post you could comment out `line 138` of `/vendor/Luracast/Restler/Autoloader.php`)

A more elegant solution has been proposed by me on GitHub:

Issue: https://github.com/Luracast/Restler/issues/195

Pull Request: https://github.com/Luracast/Restler/pull/196

By the time someone else finds this post hopefully the issue will be resolved in future versions of Restler.

Comment: That pull request is already accepted and part of Restler now!